# Understanding a topology

Tags: general-topology

I have these two diagrams.

A is a topology whereas B is not but I do not understand why B is not also a topology.

The definition of a topology is: 
Given a non empty set X, we say that $\sigma$ is a topology on X if and only if:

1)"$\phi$ and X are both to be in $\sigma$."-This is true for B.

2) "The intersection of two members of $\sigma$ is again in $\sigma$".- b and a intersect in B

3) "The union of any collection of elements of $\sigma$ is again in $\sigma$."-This is true because b is in both sets.

Why is B not a topology?

[image]

Comment: 2) fails for B. The set containing just $\{b\}$ is not a member of the topology, but arises as an intersection of such sets

Comment: Do you mean that nothing intersects?

Comment: not that "*nothing intersects*" but rather if it happens to intersect then the intersection was already a part of our list.

Comment: No. According to your diagram, in B, the sets $\{a,b\}$ and $\{b,c\}$ are sets which belong to the topology. According to 2), their intersection has to be a member of the topology, as well, but it is not.

Comment: if b and c had individual contours around them then B would become a topology. How do those extra contours change things?

Answer (score 1):

A topology is a collection of *subsets* of the space.

The (sub)sets, the elements of the topology, in in your example $B$ are $X= \{a,b,c\}$ (the full space), $S_1= \{a,b\}$, $S_2 = \{b,c\}$ and $ \emptyset = \{\}$.

Your properties need to apply to the collection/set consisting of these four. 
You clearly have 1. But you do not have 2., as the intersection of $S_1$ and $S_2$ is not any of the sets listed.

And, while you do have 3. your argument is not correct as the point is that the union of any of these four sets is still a member of these four. Note that the union of $S_1$ and $S_2$ is the full space.

Contrast with $A$. There the intersection of the two sets is the empty set and it is thus fine.

Comment: if b and c had individual contours around them then B would become a topology. How do those extra contours change things?

Comment: If in addition to the contour around $b$ and $c$ there would be individual contours around each of $b$ and $c$ too, then yes this would be a toplogy. (Indeed the one around $b$ suffices for that.) On "how do those [...] change things." Formally, if you have a contour around $b$ then you also have the subset $\{b\}$ available. And with that in addition the conditions are met. If you rather meant why this change intuitively should make a difference, then this amounts to asking why a topology is defined as it is. This is a relevant question but a quite different one.

Comment: ok so in a nutshell do we need every individual subset to be specified? For example there was no $\{b\}$ but adding a contour gives you $\{b\}$ so it becomes a topology?

Comment: No you do not need every singleton in the topology. In fact if you have every singleton in the topology then the toplogy will have to be equal to the set of all subsets. This is the so called discrete topology, but this is not a that interesting topology usually. What you do need is that if you have two sets in the topology then you also have the set that is their intersection in the topology. And the same for unions; indeed for unions you need to consider arbitrary unnions not just unions of two sets.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas comment $\{a, b\}\cap\{ b,c\}=\{ b\}$ but  we see that $\{b\}\not\in B$

Comment: Why is b not in B? I thought if it is in the venn diagram then it is in B?

Comment: @  Al jabra ,see :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206685/need-help-with-understanding-th‌​e-basis-for-a-topology?rq=1

Comment: Tried reading that, still does not make sense.

Comment: if b and c had individual contours around them then B would become a topology. How do those extra contours change things?